# Need help running automatic tasks on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, ftp

We run a server hosted with Go-Daddy and use SQL Server 2005 Express. One of our customers needs to schedule an automatic SQL process overnight that takes the data from an ftp transfer that feed the csvs onto our server. We upgraded to SQL Server Workgroup on go-daddy but the have told us that although we can select the SQL Agent option, the ability to edit this does not appear in the SSMS as Go Daddy tell me they only supply the Express version rather than the standard version with all of the SQL packages and the express version of SSMS does not support this auto scheduling.

Can anyone advise as to how we might be able to do this either through SQL Server itself (without having to dump the go-daddy version and pay $5000 for the software from MS; or alternatively a third party plugin that will do this?

Answer (score 0):

If they're saying that you've got access to agent, then you'll have to manage the agent jobs manually. The stored procs that you'll be looking at are [sp_add_job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182079.aspx), [sp_add_jobserver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178625.aspx) (which you need to do even if you're just adding the same server you're running on), [sp_add_jobstep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187358.aspx) and [sp_add_schedule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187320.aspx). They exist in msdb, not master, so you need to explicitly switch to msdb or include that db in your EXEC calls.

Comment: @marc_s - he said that they've upgrade their SQL Server, but they've only got SSMS express.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have SQL server workgroup edition so can tick the box in options to enable sql agent but cannot then access it through SSMS as it is only express.

Answer (score 0):

I've rolled my own scheduler by writing a simple console program in c# which calls the stored procedures I need to have run.  Then I schedule this console program using windows scheduler.  All you really need are the procedure names and a connection string to the database.